# COUNTIFS yesterday?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I currently have the formula (shown below) that lets me count records with yesterday's date on.

```
=COUNTIFS(A100:A6228,"="&TODAY()-1)
```

The problem with this formula is that on a Monday when I go to use it, I get a total of 0 because the day before is Sunday.

I'm looking for a solution that uses weekdays only (mon-fri). So when I go to use the formula on Monday I get records from the Friday before.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
TODAY()-1
```

use

```
WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I was googling a solution and for some reason thought I read that the WORKDAY function didn't work.

Thanks!